# How to add elements from stack in File without repeating them in file

Tags: c++, file, sequential

I have a water class. And different elements are formed in it like Steam, Rain etc with the help of inputs from the user. And as they are formed, they are written in the file.

But I want one element to be written only once i.e. if steam is formed again, it shouldn't be added again once its been added. Is it possible?

```
bool PushandWrite (Water newElement)
    {
        ifstream in ("F:\\Songs\Water.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
        if(i>=5)
        {
            cout<<"Element cannot be formed"<<endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            /Elements[i] = newElement.water;
            in>>newElement.Elements[i];
            //Elements[i] = newElement.water;
                    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j=i+1; j<5; j++)
                        {
                            if (Elements[i] == Elements [j])
                            {
                            return false;
                            }

                            else
                                return true;
                        }
                    }

        }
    }




void write2file (Water newElement)
{
    ofstream out ("F:\\Songs\Water.txt", ios::out|ios::app);

    { 
        if (PushandWrite (newElement))
        {
            out << newElement.water<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just use `if` condition to check if entry is already available then `break` and dont print/write into file.

Comment: can u guide me how can i paste in the code here. I am totally new in here so i have no idea ho to make myself very clear. I did that but its not working. Every element is added everytime its formed.

Comment: Simply Copy and paste code in your question and select code then press ctrl+K

Comment: Without a language tag, this question is hard to answer. In any case, it looks like there have been attempts to collaborate via email, and I suspect it has now been abandoned - voting to close.

Comment: The proper container for unique elements is not a stack but a set. C++ has a set type, check that out.